# Kendo UI Angular make grid row not selectable without disabling master detail

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to make a row in a Kendo UI grid unselectable.

The grid itself is a master detail grid with the following html:

```
<kendo-grid 
[kendoGridBinding]="myData" 
[data]="gridData" 
[selectable]="selectableSettings" 
kendoGridSelectBy 
[selectedKeys]="mySelectedKeys"
[rowClass]="isDisabled"
>

<kendo-grid-checkbox-column width="40" [ngClass]="{'k-state-selected': false}">
</kendo-grid-checkbox-column>

<kendo-grid-column field="jobDisplayName" title="Job Display Name">
</kendo-grid-column>

<kendo-grid-column field="nrItems" title="Nr Items in MID">
</kendo-grid-column>

<kendo-grid-column field="status" title="status">
</kendo-grid-column>

<ng-template kendoGridDetailTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <app-ab-status-tasks-grid [tasks]="dataItem.tasks"></app-ab-status-tasks-grid>
</ng-template>
</kendo-grid>
```

I added a isDisabled function which sets k-state-disabled class

```
    public isDisabled(args) {
  return {
       'k-state-disabled': (<ActiveJob>args.dataItem).jobStatus != selectableState
   };  
}
```

This does make the row unselectable, however it also disables the master detail functionality.

[image: disabledrow]

So at 1, it's not possible to click the plus sign and view the detail for this row.

Is there a way to disable just the checkbox?

I also found that adding 'disabled' to the checkbox element doesn't work.
This is probably because the row itself is still selectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Kendo support there is a solution, so if it can help others here is the setup.

Use [rowClass] on the grid and the following function:

```
rowCallback(context: RowClassArgs) {    
  return {        
    'DisableRowSelection': !canBeOveridden
  };
}
```

And the following css:

```
.k-grid .k-grid-content tr.DisableRowSelection td:not(.k-hierarchy-cell) {
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```